# Accessing the attributes of a file connection created via file()

Tags: r, file, connection-string, file-connection

I'm creating a file connection via `path <- file("C:/test.txt")` and when printing the object associated to the connection I can **see** the connection's "attributes":

```
> path
  description         class          mode          text        opened 
"C:/test.txt"        "file"           "r"        "text"      "closed" 
     can read     can write 
        "yes"         "yes"
```

However, I can't seem to figure out how to actually **access** the various attribute values

Here's what I tried so far:

```
> attributes(path)
$class
[1] "file"       "connection"

$conn_id
<pointer: 0x0000004b>

> path$description
Error in path$description : $ operator is invalid for atomic vectors

> path["description"]
[1] NA

> file.info(path)
Error in file.info(path) : invalid filename argument
```

Any ideas?

Comment: What are the attributes you want to access ?

Comment: *Attributes* is probably not the correct term, but I simply mean the things I see when printing the object attached to the connection: "description", "mode", "opened" etc.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

A quick look at `base:::print.connection` will show that you want `summary(path)`.

```
summary(path)
$description
[1] "C:/test.txt"

$class
[1] "file"

$mode
[1] "r"

$text
[1] "text"

$opened
[1] "closed"

$`can read`
[1] "yes"

$`can write`
[1] "yes"
```

Comment: And me by 1 minute :) Leaving answer anyway, since my code snippet shows how to get an "attribute".

Comment: Duh, unbelievable that I didn't think of the good ol' `summary()`. Thanks man!

Comment: @Rappster -- I was surprised to see that too. (I found it by typing `class(path)`, then trying `getAnywhere("print.file")`, then `getAnywhere("print.connection")`.)

Comment: Yet another example why I love SO that much. In a way, it's like "decentralized pair programming", someone always has got some helpful idea ;-)

Answer (score 1):

The closest I can get to what you want is to use *summary()*. For example:

```
summary(path)$mode
[1] "rt"
```

The error using *file.info()* is because that function expects the path to the file, *i.e.* "C:/test.txt", as its argument.

Comment: I'll go with Josh as he's been a little faster ;-) Nevertheless thanks for the answer!